# Wicket string model

Tags: java, model, wicket

Im still not getting the wicket models. What am I doing wrong here? filterString is still "" when the links onClick method prints it.

```
class X extends Panel {
    String filterString;
    TextField filterTextField;
    AjaxLink filterLink;

   X(){
       filterString = new String("");
       filterTextField = new TextField<String>("filterTextField", new PropertyModel<String>(this, "filterString"));
       filterLink = new AjaxLink<Void>("filterLink"){
           private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
           @Override
           public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {              
               params.setFilterString(filterTextField.getModelObject());
               System.out.println("BLABLABLA " + filterTextField.getModelObject());
           }
       };
       //add stuff etc
    }
}
```

EDIT:

OK, like Juha said using a Form works. Sometimes I feel like creating forms feels like overkill but since this is probably the most Wicket-y thing to do anyway, it is what I will use here. The class would look something like this:

```
public class X extends Panel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public X(String id) {
        super(id);
        add(new FilterForm("logEntryForm"));
    }

    public class FilterForm extends Form{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private transient String text; //no need to serialize this
        public FilterForm(String id) {
            super(id);
            final TextField<String> contents = new TextField<String>("contents", new PropertyModel<String>(FilterForm.this, "text")); //textArea for user to enter the filter String
            add(contents);
            add(new AjaxButton("filterButton") {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                @Override
                protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
                    //do stuff, in my case it was to send the text to the database for filtering out results
                }
            }); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Having to add the form has nothing to do with Wicket, but everything with how the Web works: a browser will not submit any value to the server unless it is in a form, *or* if you use Ajax to update the component's value. It's the web, live with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `AjaxLink` with `Form` and `AjaxButton` or something that has `onSubmit()` method. AjaxLink doesn't do submit so browser doesn't send the input value to server.

Comment: So the onClick method will never work to get the value from the user? Seems odd to me since Im explicitly telling it to.

Comment: You either directly ask the Textfield for it value (not the model) and work with that. Or you can listen to Juha. Put a form in, and use a submit component.

Comment: Which method do I use to get its value? getInput() or..?

Comment: @fred Ask yourself this: when you click the link in the browser, how does the link know that it also has to send the value of a completely unrelated text field back to the server? Just because you put something in the Java code, the HTML isn't going to change. A HTML form serves exactly this purpose: to group a set of input fields into a data set that is to be submitted together.

Comment: @biziclop Sure, its just that with AJAX, there isnt necessarily any need for forms. As far as I get it anyway.

Comment: @biziclop, you're wrong, that's the whole point of AJAX, not needing any kind of forms.

Comment: @rotsch Yes, because AJAX is magic and it just knows what you want to send. :) You can choose not to use forms but then you have to use something equivalent to forms. You have to tell the browser somehow that if you click link X, the value of field Y has to be posted. That's for all intents and purposes a form, even if it isn't represented in html with a `<form>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

In constructor it seems you have written `x()` rather than `X()` (capital X)

Comment: The class name and its constructor here is not important, its just an example. The issue is the use of models. Thanks for your heads up on the typo though.

Comment: @fred But try to provide syntactically correct code while putting questions. Because it itself was an error.